# Form AJAX callback ignore validation

Tags: 8

I've defined an callback:

```
$form['process'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Process'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => 'Drupal\custom_graph\Form\ExamplePageForm::exampleCallback',
    'wrapper' => 'example',
  ],
];

$form['example'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => 'example',
  ]
];

if ($form_state->hasValue('process')) {
  $form['example']['hello'] = [
    '#markup' => 'Hello',
  ];
}
```

The callback returns the example part of the form.

```
  public function exampleCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['example'];
  }
```

However since I have a title field that is required as well:

```
$form['title'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
];
```

The error message from that field is appended to the example container. I've tried add `#limit_validation_errors()` but when I do, the hello is not appended as expected (the form state seems empty)

What is the proper way to do this semi- callback that does stuff and builds up on the form?

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly the problem is.